# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class (Using formtastic in Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

A tad bit confused as to why this isn't working. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 with Rails 3.0.3 on Windows 7.

Trying to make a form with formtastic for a post model, however, I keep getting **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class** when I try to render the view.

Relevant code:

Demonly_controller.rb

```
class DemonlyController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @post = Post.all
    end
end
```

Posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

end
```

*Post.rb*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :post, :date, :time, :user, :visible, :comments
end
```

*Index.html.erb*

```
<h1>Demonly</h1>
<% semantic_form_for @post do |f|%>
  <%= f.errors %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :post %>
    <%= f.input :date %>
    <%= f.input :time %>
    <%= f.input :user %>
    <%= f.input :visible %>
    <%= f.input :comments %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's rather likely that I'm doing something very stupid seeing as I'm sick and mentally cloudy.

Extracted source (around line #2):

1. <% semantic_form_for @post do |f|%>
2. <%= f.errors %>
3. <%= f.inputs do %>
4. <%= f.input :title %>

Let me know if anything else is needed.

**EDIT**: Forgot to change some things back.

Forgot to include the db schema:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "post"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.string   "user"
    t.boolean  "visible"
    t.boolean  "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: In your view you have `@posts` and in your controller you define `@post` (not plural)

Comment: What do you want the form for? Creating a new post? Editing all posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Erm, several problems:

- You have two controllers and haven't said which is the relevant one
- PostsController has `@post = Post.all` outside of a method context
- Neither of your controllers is setting the plural `@posts` referenced in your view

Comment: Woops, demonly_controller.rb is the relevant controller, @post = Post.all in posts_controller.rb shouldn't be there, and semantic_form_for @posts should be @post. Index.html.erb is demonlycontroller's index view.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `@post = Post.all`, it should be a plural. In any case even if you do get an array, that's not a suitable argument to `semantic_form_for`. You appear to be confused about the meaning of the seven resource actions in rails. Perhaps you want the show action instead?

Comment: It's been a very slow day. It should have been Post.new, not Post.all. Added in resources :posts to my routes.rb file and now it works perfect. Thank you!